# SOLR how to get the SolrInputDocument from a SolrResponse in order to update a document?

Tags: solr

When I try this code, I have a log saying

`Call to undefined method SolrQueryResponse::getInputDocument() in...`

```
$solrQueryResponse->setParseMode(\SolrQueryResponse::PARSE_SOLR_DOC);
$res = $solrQueryResponse->getResponse();
$doc = $res->response->docs[0]->getInputDocument();
```

Comment: Which version of the Solr extension are you using? The error message also seems to indicate that you're calling the method on the response object and not the document object.

Comment: Thanks fors your response Mats ! I m using version 2.3.0... Yes I m calling on the response object as I want to retrieve the document from a query to update it. I dont know if there is a better way...

Comment: If you're implementing this code as a plugin, I have uploaded a few examples on [my repository](https://github.com/lttazz99/SolrPluginsExamples) on github that could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response Binoy but your example is a little bit too complicated for me and not in php. I was asking for a basic use case "updater and existing entry"... it would not be more than 3 lines of code. I did it by requesting an existing id, parsing the reponse reacreating by myself a new solr entry and adding with the same id. It works but it seems too be a very heavy way.... I was wondering if there is not a better way with this method called getInputDocument (or another) that I dont know how to use...